# Android authentication on Keycloak with identity providers like Google and Facebook

Tags: java, android, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am creating a native android application and I am using keycloak authentication, because my web app and my API is already configured with keycloak. I setup Facebook and Google as identity providers for keycloak but now I don't know how I am supposed to configure it in the Android application.

For the general authentication I am using retrofit with rest calls to get the token and after that I am storing the token in Android Account manager.

I want my android app to successfully authenticate via Facebook or Google through Keycloak. Any suggestions, please?